# check a specific submit button value in controller (Yii2)

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

how to check a submit button value in controller (Yii2). I am working with multiple submit button.

I tried simple php code. but it is not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['next']) && $_POST['next']=='gotocartfive')
```

**code in view is :**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(); ?>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo Html::submitButton('NEXT',array('value'=>'gotocartfive','name' => 'next','id'=>'next_summary','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right')); ?>
    <?php echo Html::submitButton('PREVIOUS',array('value'=>'previous_four','name' => 'cartfour','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-left')); ?>
</div>  
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: can you post your form code?

Comment: show your view code ..

Comment: <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(); ?>
  
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo Html::submitButton('NEXT',array('value'=>'gotocartfive','name' => 'next','id'=>'next_summary','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right')); ?>
      <?php echo Html::submitButton('PREVIOUS',array('value'=>'previous_four','name' => 'cartfour','class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-left')); ?>
</div>  
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit 1', ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'submit_1']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit 2', ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'submit_2']) ?>
```

PHP

```
If (\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
   switch (\Yii::$app->request->post('action')) {
      case 'submit_1':

      case 'submit_2':

   }
}
```

When you submit form by pressing enter (without click any submit button), submit_1 will be default value.

Comment: Thanks. it seems working. But, I have to click the button two times.The first click does not do anything. Is there anything more to do?

Comment: Your problem is same to https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10555. When you click submit button, if that button has attribute name, yii.activeForm.js when add a hidden input with name is same to button's name. See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/10625/files for the solution

Comment: Do not _name_ the button _submit_, otherwise you’ll have to click twice on the button to submit the form.

Comment: Note: This only works with normal form submission and not when using Pjax for form submission

Comment: I am not able to get the name can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66963449/6854117) related to it?

Comment: @VănQuyết I have tried it but still the same result. I  have  to click the  submit  button twice

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code.

Code in view file.

```
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove'), ['class' => 'btn red', 'name' => 'submit', 'value' => '0']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Save'), ['class' => 'btn blue', 'name' => 'submit', 'value' => '1']) ?>
```

Code in controller action

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {

  if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit') == 0) {
     //Code for value 0
  }

  if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit') == 1) {
    //Code for value 1
  }

}
```

Please let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: As per the above comments, do not name it 'submit'. otherwise you will need to click twice because it uses jquery to add a hidden variable

Comment: @LionelYeo I have named both of them separately but still it hits the `0` condition

Comment: @Faisal try ```name=>"action" val=>"0" and name="action" , val=>"1"```

Comment: @LionelYeo again same issue

Comment: @LionelYeo I am not able to get the name can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66963449/6854117) related to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

View File

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(); ?>
<div class="form-group">
  <?= Html::submitButton('NEXT',[ 'name'=>'submit', 'value' => 'next', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) ?>
  <?= Html::submitButton('PREVIOUS',[ 'name'=>'submit', 'value' => 'previous', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right') ?>
</div>  
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller File

```
public function actionYourControllerName()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit') && $_POST['submit']=='next') 
    {
      // your code
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='previous') 
    {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any other way  rather than to use `isset($_POST['submit'))` >?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add this little js snippet to your project and bind it to [beforeSubmit](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L410) event in yii.activeForm.js like this:

```
(function ($) { 
    var formId = !!yiiconfig.viewPolicyParams && yiiconfig.viewPolicyParams.formId && yiiconfig.viewPolicyParams.formId, 
        $form = formId && $("#" + formId);

    /**
     * Updates hidden field that represents clicked submit button.
     * @param event event object triggered
     */
    function updateHiddenButton (event) {
        var $buttons = $form.find(':submit');

        $buttons.length && $buttons.each(function (i,b) {
            var $hiddenButton = $('input[type="hidden"][name="' + $(b).attr('name') + '"]', $form);
            $hiddenButton.length && $hiddenButton.remove();
        });

    };

    $form && $form.bind('beforeSubmit.' + formId, updateHiddenButton);

} (jQuery));
```

This code removes all hidden inputs which are being created by yii.activeForm before submitting. 
Then after this inputs will be recreated by yii.activeForm.

hope this helps