# Q: Yii2 integrating Rbac and button discrimination

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I'm developing a website in php with Yii2 and I have a problem with Rbac issue. I've followed the offical guide, I run the migrations and now I have in my db the four default tables which define my roles and permissions. Now I don't know how to integrate these roles in my project, I mean I would like to have some views only visible to users with specific permissions but can't understand the way to implement this.

I have also a problem with login, I don't know how to discriminate a button click.

login (view):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button', 'value' => 'login']) ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'register-button', 'value' => 'register']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

SiteController:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='login') {
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='register') {

        return $this->render('register');
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I just need to render in a different views the user after the right button click. If Login button is clicked I want to be redirected in login view, if Register button is clicked, I want to be redirected in register view.

Comment: Does the Button Register work? Do you have an actionRegister?

Comment: Button Register doesn't work, it makes the same thing as Login button. I don't have an actionRegister, just actionLogin you see.

Comment: it's better to use Yii::$app->request->post() and you have 2 buttons submit for the same form? isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a two-in-one question.

First, RBAC.

This is explained very well in the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization). You can use AccessControl to only allow certain actions to be accessed by a role or permission. If you need to show some content in a view based on a role or permission, use `if(Yii::$app->user->can('permission_or_role)) echo "I can";` ([docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#can()-detail)).

Second, buttons

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496710/check-a-specific-submit-button-value-in-controller-yii2) link, the name of the button must be the name you check for in the controller (not `login-button`/`register-button` and check `submit`).