# Yii2: How to send data outside of a $model?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, yii2, hidden-field

I use Yii2 to send a form with one model using this submit button from the view to its controller:

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Also need to send a boolean variable to the controller when the button is pressed but I don't know how to include it **outside** of the model.

I can resolve it defining a **Html::hiddenInput()** but it will include the new hidden field into $model.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need.. A bool value when the button is pressed? You can pass a value from the button, read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496710/check-a-specific-submit-button-value-in-controller-yii2

Comment: not clear what you are asking, can you describe the actual scenario for which you need to pass this `boolean` value. and including a hidden input inside the form won't require to add or define anything in the model unless its an `activeHiddenInput()`

Answer (score 1):

In what I understand you need to know when user pressed the submit button, so you must set the **name** attribute for submit button. You can set that attribute in options. 
Example for your question

```
Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary','name'=>'submit-btn','value'=>($model->isNewRecord? 'create' : 'update')])
```

for more info read this link [submitButton](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#submitButton()-detail) or [submitInput](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#submitInput()-detail).

For handle request in controller use **Yii::$app->request->post()**:

Example:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
if(isset($post['submit-btn']) && ($post['submit-btn'] == 'create')){
       /** Your Code */ 
}
```